# изменение размеров divа на введеные в форме

Tags: jquery

Нужно на jquery сделать так, чтобы пользователь вводил в инпуты высоту и ширину, а див с id target менял размеры свои.

HTML:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
    <title>123</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"> </script>
</head>

<body>

    <script>
    </script>


    <div>
        Изменяем размер div'а <br>
    <input type="text" class="var" id="x" placeholder="введите высоту"> <br>
        <input type="text" class="var" id="y" placeholder="введите ширину"> <br>
        <input type="button" id="button" value="изменить размер">
    </div>

    <div id="target"> Тот самый div </div>

</body>

</html>
```

CSS:

```
  .var {
        background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
        color: black;
        border-width: 1px;
        border-style: solid;
        margin: 10px;
        padding: 6px 10px;
        width: 130px;
        transition: 1s;
    }

    .var:focus {
        color: #1E90FF;
        outline-color: #1E90FF;
        transition: 1s;
    }

    #button {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: black;
        border-width: 1px;
        border-style: solid;
        padding: 5px 10px;
        margin: 10px;
        width: 130px;
        transition: 1s;
    }
    #button:hover {
        color: #1E90FF;
        transition: 1s;
    }

    #target {
        width: 150px;
        height: 150px;
        border-width: 1px;
        border-style: solid;
        margin: 10px;
        text-align: center;
        background: #1E90FF;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$( ".var" ).change(function() {
 var valus = parseInt($(this).val());
  var prop = $(this).is("#x") ? "height" : "width";
  if(!isNaN(valus)){
  $("#target").css(prop, valus)
 }
});
```

```css
.var {
        background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
        color: black;
        border-width: 1px;
        border-style: solid;
        margin: 10px;
        padding: 6px 10px;
        width: 130px;
        transition: 1s;
    }

    .var:focus {
        color: #1E90FF;
        outline-color: #1E90FF;
        transition: 1s;
    }

    #button {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: black;
        border-width: 1px;
        border-style: solid;
        padding: 5px 10px;
        margin: 10px;
        width: 130px;
        transition: 1s;
    }
    #button:hover {
        color: #1E90FF;
        transition: 1s;
    }

    #target {
        width: 150px;
        height: 150px;
        border-width: 1px;
        border-style: solid;
        margin: 10px;
        text-align: center;
        background: #1E90FF;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>

    <div>
        Изменяем размер div'а <br>
    <input type="text" class="var" id="x" placeholder="введите высоту"> <br>
        <input type="text" class="var" id="y" placeholder="введите ширину"> <br>
        <input type="button" id="button" value="изменить размер">
    </div>

    <div id="target"> Тот самый div </div>

</body>
```

Comment: Спасибо, не думал, что можно настолько коротко это записать :\

Comment: можете тип инпуту выставить number,  и тогда можна проверку убрать из кода js на число.